# pstack not printing stack output

Tags: stack

I am running pstack to find function stack for my application running on two machines (both RHEL)

In one of my machine it is working as expected

```
[root@civ4cez191 bin]# pstack 22947
Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f63cbe7d700 (LWP 22949)):
#0  0x0000003c3640f0cd in pause () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000485a78 in _signalWaitThread(void*) ()
#2  0x0000003c36407aa1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x0000003c360e8aad in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f63d2d07700 (LWP 22947)):
#0  0x0000003c360e1523 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004ccc36 in TFDSETSelect(void*, void*, int) ()
#2  0x00000000004cb50f in SvrInit1(unsigned int (*)(void*, void**), unsigned int (*)(void*, void*, void**, unsigned int*), void (*)(void*), unsigned int (*)(unsigned short, unsigned short), void (*)(unsigned short, unsigned short), void (*)(unsigned short, unsigned short), unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned char) ()
#3  0x00000000004259f0 in main ()
```

However in other machine it is just printing name of the threads

```
[root@civ4cez194 bin]# pstack 12672
Thread 7 (Thread 0x7f01892e2700 (LWP 12674)):
Thread 6 (Thread 0x7f0188aa0700 (LWP 12743)):
Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f0188a1e700 (LWP 7090)):
Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f0188a5f700 (LWP 7127)):
Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f01889dd700 (LWP 7178)):
Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f0188ae1700 (LWP 7235)):
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f0193ca0740 (LWP 12672)):
```

I have looked for a way to resolve this but haven't had much success. Only significant information I found was [here](http://gnu.wiki/man1/pstack.1.php)

```
For thread information to be dumped, you have to use the debug-aware version of the LinuxThreads libpthread.so library.
(To check, run nm(1) on your pthreads library, and
make sure that the symbol "__pthread_threads_debug" is defined.) Threads are not supported with the newer NPTL libpthread.so library.
```

On doing nm on /lib64/libpthread.so.0 on both the machines, the only debug related field I could find was  "__pthread_debug", however it is present in both.

Will appreciate help.

Comment: The message says to look for ``__pthread_threads_debug`` and you say you found ``__pthread_debug``.  They’re not the same. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Ah, I was confused by the statement “In one of my machine[s] it is working as expected”.   Actually the issue is that one machine is working unexpectedly, and the other is failing as expected.

Comment: I didn't understand previous comment @G-Man

Comment: I’m saying that, if `__pthread_threads_debug` must be defined for `pstack` to work correctly (to dump thread information), and `__pthread_threads_debug` isn’t defined on either machine, then it’s a mystery why the first machine is working.  I guess I was being a little snarky; I apologize.  But I’m serious. P.S. It would be nice if you would identify the source of that “For thread information to be dumped” statement.

Comment: @G-Man Sorry The link was removed while copy pasting from stackoverflow editing it.

Comment: Please don’t [post the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50435578/3960947) on multiple [SE] sites (that includes [SO]) at the same time.   Moderators: Don’t migrate this question to [SO]; it’s already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there was issue with python installation on the setup due to which backtrace was not working, fixing python installation fixed the problem.